# Javascript function does not affect Angular templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom

I have set up a simple angular project where I have a base template. This base template imports all the necessary libraries, and also runs a simple jQuery function in it. Something like this:

```
<html ng-app='myApp'>
    <body>
        <div><input type="text"></div>
        <div ng-view></div>
        // Imports
        <script>
            (function() {
                $('input').each(function() {
                    $(this).addClass('doSomething');
                });
            })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So, basically, the function adds a class to all the input elements in my DOM. The first input element outside of the ng-view is affected by this function.

However, lets say I have input elements in my ng-view templates, these are weirdly not affected by the function. Why is that? It seems my jQuery function can't access the DOM of my Angular templates.

Is there a solution to this? What's the ideal way to run a common function that can affect Angular templates?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you do (or search if one already exists) a directive ?

Comment: And adding a class to every input seems that you should use a simple CSS class : `input { your_code }`

Comment: @Maxime Why would you prefer using an element name as a selector over a class?

Comment: @1252748 because if you have to use some javascript to insert that class everywhere, why not just use the css selector ?

Comment: The addClass thing was just for the question obviously. The real function does a lot of other things, I did not want to include an extra 15+ lines of code for the question.

Answer (score 0):

The templates aren't somehow implicitly 'included'; they get *constructed* by the angular code on the fly (and potentially based on asynschronous events like http requests that occur after the main page onload event has triggered). So you can't guarantee that the DOM will have been constructed by angular unless you cooperate with angular in some way.

The 'right' way to approach this probably to write an angular directive for 'input' tags that adds the class (rather than using jQuery as you do above); and certainly it is the 'right' way to add event listeners, etc.